# Laravel Mysql JOIN not working

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables:

I need to get the table2 rows for each table 1 rows if table2.id=table1.id are equal.

I need something like this:
t1.row1=array("t2.row1","t2.row2" etc.);

I used this:

```
$first= DB::table('resurse')
    ->join('alocare', function($join)
    {
        $join->on( 'resurse.id', '=','alocare.resursa');
    })
   ->groupBy('id')->get();
var_dump($first);
```

the response is:

```
    array (size=2)
0 => 
object(stdClass)[159]
  public 'id' => int 1
  public 'denumire' => string 'APAD' (length=4)
  public 'id_aloc' => int 1
  public 'resursa' => int 1
  public 'subunitate' => int 1
  public 'status' => string 'btn btn-danger' (length=14)
1 => 
  object(stdClass)[160]
  public 'id' => int 2
  public 'denumire' => string 'AD' (length=2)
  public 'id_aloc' => int 3
  public 'resursa' => int 2
  public 'subunitate' => int 2
  public 'status' => string 'btn btn-danger' (length=14)
```

Comment: what is the response, can you mention here?

Comment: `            $queries = \DB::getQueryLog();
            $last_query = end($queries);
            dd($last_query);`
Check the generated the query and than run this query to mysql.

Comment: by review response, you get two record.

Comment: yes but I need to get more results from alocare tabel for each row from resurse table

Comment: and I need to create an array with alocare table result  for each row from resurse table

Comment: please take a look to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to you comment, i can assume these solutions to your question:
Get data from database with join in Laravel.

```
DB::table('resurse')
->rightJoin('alocare', 'resurse.id', '=', 'alocare.resursa')
->groupBy('resurse.id')
->get();
```

And if you want to select col from both table.

```
DB::table('resurse')
->rightJoin('alocare', 'resurse.id', '=', 'alocare.resursa')
->select('resurse.*','alocare.*')
->groupBy('resurse.id')
->get();
```

And also if you want to convert your result into array.

```
DB::table('resurse')
->rightJoin('alocare', 'resurse.id', '=', 'alocare.resursa')
->select('resurse.*','alocare.*')
->groupBy('resurse.id')
->get()->toArray();
```

I'm using right join because you also need data from alocare table.

If still something not meeting your desired, let me know.